# Simple function test of session value failing

Tags: python, flask, session, python-unittest

Didn't put in enough information the first time. Trying this again. I have the following function:

```
def do_login(user):
    """Log in user."""

    session["curr_user"] = user.id
```

It, along with this function,

```
@app.before_request
def add_user_to_g():
    """If we're logged in, add curr user to Flask global."""

    if "curr_user" in session:
        # updating to more current syntax
        g.user = db.session.query(User).get(session["curr_user"])

    else:
        g.user = None
```

is the method I'm using to keep users logged in in my flask app. It puts the users ID number in the browser session from which it can be added to flask's global object. I know the functions work because uses can perform tasks requiring authentication on the front end. It's definitely functioning correctly.

However,the following test:

```
class UserViewTestCase(TestCase):
    """Test views for users."""

    def setUp(self):
        """Create test client, add sample data."""

        User.query.delete()
        Message.query.delete()

        self.client = app.test_client()

        self.testuser = User.signup(username="testuser",
                                    email="test@test.com",
                                    password="testuser",
                                    image_url=None,
                                    header_image_url=None,
                                    bio=None,
                                    location=None)
        self.testuser2 = User.signup(username='testuser2', 
                                     email='test2@test.com', 
                                     password='testuser',
                                     image_url=None,
                                     header_image_url=None,
                                     bio=None,
                                     location=None)
        db.session.commit()
        
        self.msg1 = Message(text="testing 1", user_id = self.testuser.id)
        self.msg2 = Message(text="testing 2", user_id = self.testuser2.id)
        db.session.add_all([self.msg1, self.msg2])
        db.session.commit()

        self.testuser.following.append(self.testuser2)
        db.session.add(self.testuser)
        db.session.commit()
    def test_do_login(self):
        """Does do_login function work?"""
        with app.test_request_context():
            with self.client as c:
                with c.session_transaction() as session:
                    do_login(self.testuser)

                    self.assertEqual(session["curr_user"], self.testuser.id)
```

is throwing a KeyError failure. I know that that means there is no value for `curr_user` in the browser session, but I don't understand why the test isn't working when the actual site works fine. I assume I've done something wrong in my test having to do with the session, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question without having more context about what `session` and `CURR_USER_KEY` even are. Where are these variables defined?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your test tries to access `session[CURR_USER_KEY]` twice: once in `do_login`, and once in the call to `self.assertEqual`. If the key doesn't exist, then `do_login` is raising the exception.

If that's the expected behavior, you should use `self.assertRaises` to execute the function so that you can test that `KeyError` really is raised.

```
def test_do_login(self):
    """Does do_login function work?"""
    with app.test_request_context():
        with self.client as c:
            with c.session_transaction() as session:
                with self.assertRaises(KeyError):
                    do_login(self.testuser)
```

If that's *not* the expected behavior, and `do_login` is supposed to *add* an entry to the session so that

```
self.assertEqual(session[CURR_USER_KEY], self.testuser.id)
```

will succeed, then you have discovered a bug in `do_login` that needs to be fixed.

Comment: But the function works fine when I'm using the site.

Comment: Then the expected user exists. That doesn't change the fact that your function depends on pre-existing state that your test environment doesn't have, so either your test environment needs to change, or you have a bug in your function that needs to be fixed as I described above.